# debug watches not work?

Tags: java, android, debugging

Watches in debug mode are not working properly. As you can see [here in the screenshot](https://snag.gy/jnXSmV.jpg) variable `value = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));` is not null. I have pasted same in the watches and getting `NullPointerException`. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: check the error message after the NullPointerException, on the right of the screen

Comment: @VladMatvienko I'm getting null at this varaible MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA